# What ocean biome spawns the most fish?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a fish trap but my current ocean doesn't have 
much fish in it. I have turned mob spawning: ON.

Answer (score 1):

Fish spawn in all ocean biome variants that can spawn in at the same rate. If you want salmon and cod specifically, you should avoid lukewarm and warm oceans to prevent pufferfish and tropical fish from spawning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in a river? There is usually a plenty of salmons and squids in it.

Comment: The question is about ocean biomes, and, in any case, a good answer would include reasons to back up the suggestion (like a comparison, i.c.).

Comment: @Joachim Rivers are a biome.

Comment: I know for a fact drowned spawn in (non-frozen) river biomes at many times (IIRC 200x?) the rate of spawning in the ocean. Due to much lower natural spawning volume (simply less water) the rates are inflated so that any could spawn there at all. As result, river biomes are vastly better for drowned farms than oceans. I'd expect fish spawn rates to be similarly higher, for the same reason.